# How to generate standalone parser in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, tatsu

I would like to generate a Python parser for a custom language. As I am new to parsing, my only requirement so far is that the generated module shall not depend on the generator.

I learned Tatsu, as it can generate the parser as Python module. But when I review the generated module, it still begins with

```
from tatsu.buffering import Buffer
from tatsu.parsing import Parser
from tatsu.parsing import tatsumasu, leftrec, nomem
...
```

Is there a way to generate standalone (depending only on standard Python libraries) parser module using Tatsu? If not, do I have any other option?

Comment: Why is it important that the module should not have dependencies?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon It would be a plugin for Blender. They bundle their own Python installation, and I don't want to introduce a new dependency there.

Comment: Most parser generators I know _copy_ the dependencies into the generated code. TatSu chooses to import them.

Comment: look into how [typed_ast](https://github.com/python/typed_ast) was created (copypsated parts of the cpython parser)

Answer (score 1):

[Lark](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a pure Python parsing library, can generate a small standalone parser for any LALR(1) grammar you throw at it:

> The resulting parser is much smaller than Lark itself, it loads much faster because the grammar is pre-compiled, and it's just as easy to use.

Links:

- [Create a stand-alone LALR(1) parser in Python](http://blog.erezsh.com/create-a-stand-alone-lalr1-parser-in-python/) on the author's blog.
- [Working example](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/tree/master/examples/standalone) on GitHub.

Edit: I first wrote "any context-free grammar", but it is just LALR(1). Thanks Erez for the correction.

Comment: Lark can generate a stand-alone parser for LALR(1) grammars only, not every CFG. It can parse every CFG using Earley, but then you need to import the entire library.

Comment: I have modified my answer, but now I have a doubt. LALR(1) is a class of parsers, is it a class of languages too? I am new fairly new to language theory, and just started this morning to write a grammar in Lark for a small rational language.

Comment: LALR(1) is a class of parsers, and any grammar it can parse is a LALR(1) grammar, which is a subset of CFG grammars. Good luck with your grammar!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [pegen](https://github.com/we-like-parsers/pegen), by Guido van Rossum, Pablo Galindo, et al.

It is the basis for the Python parser in Python 3.9.

Comment: `pegen` does not generate a stand-alone parser. Running `python -m pegen data/expr.gram -o parser.py` (one of the provided examples) results in the following import: `from pegen.parser import memoize, memoize_left_rec, logger, Parser`